# alternative for parse_url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to the parse the URL so I can get the Id from the URL , so I am using the `parse_url()` function but `phpcs` says `The use of function parse_url() is discouraged` ,so is there any alternative for this?

My goal is to get the ID from the string, I have string like http://some.com/demo/id/23/

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `\Zend\Uri\Http` class from ZendFramework (included in Magento but not in 2.4.1 or fresher):

```
$uri = $this->zendUri->parse($yourUri);
$queryAsArray = $uri->getQueryAsArray();
```

Another methods can be found in `Zend\Uri\UriInterface`(available for same versions as mentioned above).

**UPDATE**
From comments for version ***above 2.4*** (by [0m3r](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/42758/0m3r)):

> ```
> $uri = \Laminas\Uri\UriFactory::factory($someUrl); 
> $query = $uri-> getQuery();
> ```

Comment: `getQueryAsArray` is not returning the "id" as param , I think it is looking for '?' as query param and I have param like '/id/23'

Comment: Try to use `getPath` exploded by `/`.

Comment: rather then I can direct use `explode` by 'id' in string but I don't want as I am looking for straight forward method

Comment: For Magento 2.4.1 and greater

```
$uri = \Laminas\Uri\UriFactory::factory($someUrl);
$query = $uri->getQuery();
```